# nmcli set static ip address without the DHCP?

Tags: linux-networking, nmcli

I want to assign a static IP address for the eth0 interface without the DHCP allocating a dynamic address.
i tried setting the method to manual but that did not help and i end up with 2 IPs on the interface one static and the other is dynamic.
i want to have only one static IP on the interface using nmcli

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/static.nmconnection:

```
[connection]
id=static
uuid=5da74c14-d9da-4e15-90c9-5f37913d5610
type=ethernet
interface-name=eth0
permissions=
timestamp=1584007539

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=172.17.1.222/24,172.17.0.1
dns=172.17.0.221;172.17.0.220;
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=ignore
```

ip a:

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:3b:22:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.1.222/24 brd 172.17.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 172.17.12.14/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft 602857sec preferred_lft 527257sec
inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe3b:2203/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To configure setting up a static IP configuration and disabling DHCP with `nmcli`, try running this as root:

```
nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.addresses "172.17.1.222/24"
nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.gateway "172.17.0.1"
nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.dns "172.17.0.221 172.17.0.220"
nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli con mod eth0 connection.autoconnect yes
```

Then either reboot your computer or restart `network-manager` with

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, The settings worked, but to apply it use `nmcli con up eth0` you dont need to reboot or restart the service.

Comment: Does this also work if you don't set a gateway as in your original post? Because I suffer from the exact same behaviour...